# rearranging a char array with strncpy in C

Tags: c, function, for-loop, if-statement, conditional-statements

I am trying to change the sorting of a the `arr` list which could consist of `zero, one, two` as the inputted and stored values for `arr`. The `stringreplace` function is meant to shift every single element by one so the new sorting would be `one, two, zero`. I am trying to replace the elements with one another by using the `strncpy` function but I think it is a bit faulty, how could i fix this?

strncpy function

```
char stringreplace( char a[], int b){
    for(int j = 0; j > b -1; j++){
        strncpy(a[j], a[j+1], sizeof(a));}
    for(int j = 0; j > b; j++){
        printf("%s",a[j]);}
}
```

main function

```
int main()
{
    char input[100];
    char arr[100]= {0};
    int number;
    printf("Input the number of strings: ");
    scanf("%d", &number);
    for(int i= 0; i < number; i++){
        printf("Input the number of strings: ");
        scanf("%s", input);
        arr[i] = input;
    }
    stringreplace(arr, number);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(a)` is the size of a pointer, not the length of the string.

Comment: The first two arguments to `strncpy()` have to be pointers. `a[j]` and `a[j+1]` are not pointers, they're characters.

Comment: Please turn on warnings in your code.  They will help you with bad parameters, assigning chars to pointers, and missing return statements.

Comment: `arr[i] = input` is wrong for multiple reasons.

Comment: You have lots of basic misunderstandings about how strings work in C, you need to go back to the books. Your code needs a total rewrite.

Comment: Your second `for()` in your replace function that does the printf() call - what is that supposed to print?  Right now, you pass a character into something expecting a C string.

Comment: `strncpy()` is almost *never* the correct function to use. If you want to copy a string, use `strcpy()`. If the destination isn't big enough to hold the string, you need to fix that.

Comment: It seems like your basic problem is that `arr` is supposed to be an array of strings, not a single string: `char *arr[100] = {0}`. But you need to allocate memory for each of the strings in the array.

Comment: `man strncpy` **"The strings may not overlap"** `a` overlaps `a`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may consider allocating strings dynamically, assigning a pointer for each string into an array `words`, and then rotating each pointer in the array to the left.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void lrot_words(char *words[], int n);

int main(void)
{
    char *p, word[100], *words[100];
    int i, num_words;

    printf("Enter the number of words: ");
    scanf("%d", &num_words);

    for(i =  0; i < num_words; i++){
        printf("Enter a word: ");
        scanf("%s", word);

        if ((p = malloc(strlen(word) + 1)) == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Error: malloc failed\n");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        words[i] = strcpy(p, word);
    }

    lrot_words(words, num_words);

    for (i = 0; i < num_words; i++) {
        printf("%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    return 0;
}   

void lrot_words(char *words[], int n)
{
    char *temp = words[0];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        words[i] = words[i+1];
    }

    words[i] = temp;
}
```

Comment: what is the malloc section if I may ask?

Comment: it returns a pointer to a dynamically allocated string (long enough for the characters in the word and a null character.  if the space required to store the word can't be allocated, an error message is printed and the program terminates.

Comment: Hey sorry for bothering too much but I also dont understand the reason for `char *temp = words[0]` what is that used for exactly?

Comment: Since each element in `words` is being shifted to the left once, the first pointer will be overwritten.  That means we need to store the pointer in a temporary variable which can be later appended to the end of the array after all elements have been shifted.